# Pinterest API 'bookmark' always returning the same string and data

Tags: python, rest, pagination, pinterest

I am trying to use pagination the way it is instructed in the Pinterest API Documentation, by passing 'bookmark' as a parameter to the next GET request in order to get the next batch of data.

However, the data returned is the EXACT same as the initial data I had received (without passing 'bookmark') and the value of 'bookmark' is also the same!

With this issue present, I keep receiving the same data over and over and can't get the entirety of the data. In my case I'm trying to list all campaigns.

Here is my python code:

```
url = f'https://api.pinterest.com/v5/ad_accounts/{ad_account_id}/campaigns'
payload = f"page_size=25"
headers = {
    "Accept": "text/plain",
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}"
}
response = requests.request("GET", url, data=payload, headers=headers)
print(response)
feed = response.json()
print(feed)
bookmark=''
if 'bookmark' in feed:
    bookmark = feed['bookmark']

print(bookmark)

while(bookmark != '' and bookmark != None and bookmark != 'null'):
    url = f'https://api.pinterest.com/v5/ad_accounts/{ad_account_id}/{level}s'
    payload = f"page_size=25&bookmark={bookmark}"
    headers = {
        "Accept": "text/plain",
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}"
    }
    response = requests.request("GET", url, data=payload, headers=headers)
    print(response)
    feed = response.json()
    print(feed)
    bookmark = feed['bookmark']
    print(bookmark)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your condition in `while` is wrong, therefore you end up in the same loop. I'm currently also working with Pinterest API and below is my modified implementation how to get a list of ad accounts.

Basically you're testing if the `bookmark` is `None`. If yes, then you can return the result, otherwise you append the bookmark into query parameters and call the endpoint again.

```
from app.api.http_client import HttpClient


class PinterestAccountsClient():

    def get_accounts(self, credentials) -> list[dict]:
        headers = {
            'Authorization': f"Bearer {credentials('access_token')}"
        }
        params = {
            'page_size': 25
        }

        accounts = []
        found_last_page = False
        while not found_last_page:
            try:
                response = HttpClient.get(self.listing_url, headers=headers, params=params)
                items = response.get('items', [])
                bookmark = response.get('bookmark')

                if bookmark is None:
                    found_last_page = True
                else:
                    params['bookmark'] = bookmark

                accounts.extend([{
                    'id': account['id'],
                    'name': account['name']
                } for account in items])

        return accounts
```